# Composing futures - how to get another variable associated with the result of a list of futures

Tags: scala, akka, future

I'm a bit new to future composition so I haven't figured out all the common patterns yet.

I have a list of futures but I need to associate a name with the futures when they are created so I can somehow reconcile the list.

EG if I create a list of futures like this, how can I get x to be associated with the future's result?

```
      val requestsForMaster = shardNames.map { x ⇒
        sentinel ? Request("SENTINEL", "get-master-addr-by-name", x)
      }
```

I would do something like this to get the futures into a sequence

```
      val mastersConfig = Future.sequence(requestsForMaster)
      mastersConfig.onSuccess {
        case x: List[Some[List[Some[ByteString]]]] ⇒
          self ! x.map {
            case Some(List(Some(host: ByteString), Some(port: ByteString))) ⇒    
              println("Host/port: " + host.utf8String + ":" + port.utf8String)
              Shard("name", host.utf8String, port.utf8String.toInt, None)
          }
      }
```

But when I go to create the Shard object, the name (x) isn't available and I need it in there.

Any idea as to how I can compose these to get the name in there?

Edit:
Here is the solution I used:

```
  val requestsForMaster = shardNames.map { x ⇒
        (sentinel ? Request("SENTINEL", "get-master-addr-by-name", x)).map(y ⇒ (x, y))
      }

      val mastersConfig = Future.sequence(requestsForMaster)
      mastersConfig.onSuccess {
        case x: (List[(String, Some[List[Some[ByteString]]])]) ⇒
          self ! x.map {
            case (name, Some(List(Some(host: ByteString), Some(port: ByteString)))) ⇒

              println("Name Host:port: " + name + " " + host.utf8String + ":" + port.utf8String)
              Shard("name", host.utf8String, port.utf8String.toInt, None)
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to use `map` on the request futures to pair  each response with the shard's name:

```
val requestsForMaster: List[Future[(String, Some[List[Some[ByteString]])] =
  shardNames.map { x =>
    val result = sentinel ? Request("SENTINEL", "get-master-addr-by-name", x)
    result.map(x -> _)
  }

val mastersConfig = Future.sequence(requestsForMaster)

mastersConfig.onSuccess {
  case results: List[(String, Some[List[Some[ByteString]]])] =>
    self ! results.map {
      case (x, Some(List(Some(host: ByteString), Some(port: ByteString)))) =>
        // Create the shard object.
    }
}
```

More generally, if you have a `Future[V]` and a `K`, you can create a `Future[(K, V)]` by writing `fv.map(k -> _)`.